# Class of type Blob being converted to Object in Emberjs, Electron and PouchDB/CouchDB Project

Tags: ember.js, couchdb, electron, pouchdb

i seem to be having a funny issue here. I am currently developing an offline first web application with emberjs and a desktop application wrapped in electron. Both are running off a pouchdb replicating with couchdb. I noticed images uploaded on the web are only accessible there while images uploaded from the desktop app are only accessible there too. The uploaded Blob class is only seen as blob within the environment where it was uploaded. Please i really need a pointer here

When i access the image in a different environment this is what i see

```
content_type:"image/jpeg"
data:Object
digest:undefined
length:undefined
name:"photo_record_1.jpg"
stub:undefined
__ember1493143170849:"ember775"
__ember_meta__:Meta
__proto__:Class
```

When it should be

```
__ember1493143512170:"ember788"
__ember_meta__:Meta
content_type:"image/jpeg"
data:Blob
digest:undefined
length:undefined
name:"photo_record_1.jpg"
stub:undefined
__proto__:Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by converting the image blob to base64 encode and storing this string in my CouchDB, don't know the impact of this implementation but it solves my immediate problem